# POS-tagging and then lemmatizing in python 2.7 using nltk for a large dataset (sentiment analysis)

Tags: python, nltk, pos-tagger

I'm trying to perform sentiment analysis on certain data. I want to tag the POS of the data and lemmatize it before using my algorithm for the sentiment analysis.
The algorithm is working without POS tagging and lemmatizing.

I'm getting a bad zip file error when I try to do the POS tagging using nltk.pos_tag(). 
How can I fix this issue?

Will scikit learn be a better option to perform this sentiment analysis?

`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Janak/Desktop/NaiveBayesFin.py", line 88, in <module>
    evaluate_features(make_full_dict)
  File "C:/Users/Janak/Desktop/NaiveBayesFin.py", line 42, in evaluate_features
    tagged_words = nltk.pos_tag(posWords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\__init__.py", line 110, in pos_tag
    tagger = PerceptronTagger()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\tag\perceptron.py", line 140, in __init__
    AP_MODEL_LOC = 'file:'+str(find('taggers/averaged_perceptron_tagger/'+PICKLE))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 628, in find
    return find(modified_name, paths)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 614, in find
    return ZipFilePathPointer(p, zipentry)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 561, in _decorator
    return init_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 469, in __init__
    zipfile = OpenOnDemandZipFile(os.path.abspath(zipfile))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\compat.py", line 561, in _decorator
    return init_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 979, in __init__
    zipfile.ZipFile.__init__(self, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 770, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 811, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipfile, "File is not a zip file"
BadZipfile: File is not a zip file
```

`

Comment: Are you passing in a file that you think is a zip file? Are you passing in a file that you don't think `nltk` should think is a zip file? Are you not passing in anything and have no idea why you're getting this error? What is the **code** that creates this error? Also, the question about `sklearn` is sort of separate - StackOverflow is generally about answering specific questions, in this case "How can I fix this error?". A separate question might be "is it better/easier/more accurate to use `sklearn` or `nltk` for sentiment analysis?"

Comment: Did you download the corpora first? I remember running into the same thing a few years back. Fire up an interactive shell and run `>>> import nltk` and then `>>> nltk.download()` if not.

Comment: [`nltk_cli`](https://github.com/alvations/nltk_cli) (Disclaimer: Shameless plug)

Comment: @dwanderson- Sorry, I will make sure I use two separate questions in the future. I'm not able to figure out which file is it pointing to when it says that te file is not a zip file.

Comment: @AlexHristov- Should I download the entire corpora?
I've downloaded some parts which I found to be useful in my program because the entire corpora is a bit big.